# Do I need the internet permission for Firebase/Google Mobile Ads in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, admob

I have created a Flutter application and I want to monetize it with AdMob and the offical [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) package.

My app doesn't really need the internet permission, except for the ads, but in the official documentation there isn't anything about adding the "" internet permission line for Android so I didn't added it.

In debug mode everything is working fine and the ads are showing up, but if I build the app for release, there are no ads. Do I need to add the internet permission or what is the problem here?

(I did everything like in the documentation with initialization and everything)

Answer (score 1):

**Own answer:** I have tested things out and I've found out that you don't need the internet permission for AdMob or Firebase.
I have just deleted the interstitial ad in my AdMob dashboard and created a new one and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> Note: Both the Internet and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions are
> normal permissions, which means they're granted at install time and
> don't need to be requested at runtime.

Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting